# How to check if AVPlayerViewController fast forward control has been pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, xcode7-beta3, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayerViewController and AVPlayer that shows default controls. When the player is in fullscreen the >>| button acts as a fast forward but i would like to override/delegate this to act as a next button and call my `playNextVideo()` method. Is this at all possible, or do I have to live with the fast forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

set the AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate, then use

```
-(void)playerViewController:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController willResumePlaybackAfterUserNavigatedFromTime:(CMTime)oldTime toTime:(CMTime)targetTime;
```

Comment: it's for tvOS only